# How do I get the Pwnhammer after beating the Wall of Flesh and quitting the game?

Tags: terraria-console

I wasn't aware that the loot the Wall of Flesh drops would be in a box in the air. I did get the box and I most likely did get the loot. My problem is I had left my world before I searched the internet for where it was. I play on 3DS and I don't want to defeat it again. How can I get the Pwnhammer? I know I need it and I believe you can get it by fishing but i would need a verification on that.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** get it by fishing and, other than cheats or someone else giving it to you, there is **no way to get it without defeating the wall of flesh**